# jade compiler in webstorm does not track included mixins

Tags: pug, webstorm

### Edit:

This problem is currently fixed, in webstorm 7.0.4.

---

I have the following jade compiler setup on a windows machine. My files are compiled correctly, but when I update one of the included mixins the main html file does not update.

I looked around and couldn't find a solution to this, although the LESScss compiler is working fine.

My setting is the following: (can't post image due to low reputation, I'm new here.)

```
File type: Jade
Scope: Project Files 
Program: c:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\jade.cmd $FileDri$\ --out $ProjectFileDir$\build\html 
Working directory: $ProjectFileDir$\templates
[check] create output file from stdout
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's a bug is WebStorm - please vote for [WEB-9789](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-9789)